# expectation on a chain reaction problem

Tags: probability

A total of 6 objects hide the following values: 5 cents, 10 cents, 25 cents, 50 cents, 1 chain-reaction object to discover 2 objects and 1 chain-reaction object to discover ALL objects. The player is awarded 3 picks (or untill ALL object is selected, awarding all numeric values). The chain-reaction object randomly pick 2 additional objects. What is the expectation of the total number of objects picked?

Comment: The numbers are small, so a careful cases analysis will take care of it. Not much fun.

Comment: André, I would Ippreciate if you could help me with the theoretic logic to generilize it for a larger case. Thanks

Comment: If you post a general question, and I see it, will try to answer it. It is unfortunately the case that if a problem is complicated, "closed form" solutions become less and less likely, and one may have to resort to simulations, or estimates.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  you can either pick three of the four numeric values and expose 3 (what is the chance of this?), pick two numbers and the small chain reaction for the first three and pick the other two numbers (what is the chance of this?) and get 5, or get all 6.

Comment: I have this same example with 28 Objects: 18 Numeric Objects (5 of 5 cents, 6 of 10 cents, 5 of 25 cents and 2 of 50 cents) and 10 chain-reaction objects ( 9 of them discover 2 objects and 1 object discovers ALL objects). I need to calculate the EV for this case.

Comment: @user56962:  The approach is the same.  There will be more cases, because you can keep discovering the small chain-reaction ones.